# MapFragment in ScrollView

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, google-play-services

I have one of the new [`MapFragment`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment)s in a `ScrollView`. Actually it's a `SupportMapFragment`, but anyway. It works, but there are two problems:

1. When scrolled, it leaves a black mask behind. The black covers exactly the area where the map was, except for a hole where the +/- zoom buttons were. See screenshot below. This is on Android 4.0.
2. The view doesn't use `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent()` when the user interacts with the map to prevent the `ScrollView` intercepting touches, so if you try to pan vertically in the map, it just scrolls the containing `ScrollView`. I could theoretically derive a view class `MapView` and add that functionality, but how can I get `MapFragment` to use my customised `MapView` instead of the standard one?

[image: Partial screenshot of scrolling issue]

Comment: "I have one of the new MapFragments in a ScrollView" -- I will be surprised if this works well. "how can I get MapFragment to use my customised MapView instead of the standard one?" -- you can't, AFAIK. You would have to create your own fragment for hosting your `MapView`.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue, but I'm using a raw MapView within a Fragment. Same problem, when scrolling in either a ScrollView or ViewPager the black mask is left behind.

Comment: On my Nexus S (Android 4.1.2), I'm not getting this issue. However, I'm getting exactly the same issue on all Android 2.2-2.3 devices I've tested on.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Applying a transparent image over the mapview fragment seems to resolve the issue.  It's not the prettiest, but it seems to work.   Here's an XML snippet that shows this:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView123"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/temp_transparent" />         
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I can confirm that this works (although some parts of the screen still flickers. I ended up using a FrameLayout as parent, and a plain `<View>` with `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` for the transparent view.

Comment: thanks dude i refer so many not working but yours simple and great

Comment: Is there any similar workaround when using MapView instead of MapFragment?

Answer (score 36):

For me adding a transparent ImageView did not help remove the black mask completely. The top and bottom parts of map still showed the black mask while scrolling.

So the solution for it, I found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419521/moving-mapfragment-surfaceview-causes-black-background-flickering/16554780#16554780) with a small change.
I added,

```
android:layout_marginTop="-100dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="-100dp"
```

to my map fragment since it was vertical scrollview. So my layout now looked this way:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/map_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="-100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-100dp"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/transparent_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@color/transparent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

To solve the second part of the question I set `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)` for my main ScrollView. When the user touched the transparent image and moved I disabled the touch on the transparent image for `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` so that map fragment can take Touch Events.

```
ScrollView mainScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.main_scrollview);
ImageView transparentImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.transparent_image);

transparentImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action) {
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                mainScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                // Disable touch on transparent view
                return false;

           case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // Allow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                mainScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                return true;

           case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                mainScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                return false;

           default: 
                return true;
        }   
    }
});
```

This worked for me. Hope it helps you..

Comment: @Abdul Wahab: yes. I set it up this way and i can click on Markers in the map.

Comment: Thanks, this solves both problems and that is why should be actually accepted as an answer.

Comment: mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true) doesn't work for this solution.

Answer (score 8):

This probably has its roots in the same place at causes the problem in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837697/viewpager-with-google-maps-api-v2-mysterious-black-view).  The solution there is to use a transparent frame, which is a little lighter weight than a transparent image.

Answer (score 5):

Done after lots of R&D:

**fragment_one.xml should looks like:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollViewParent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dip" >

            <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                android:id="@+id/mapView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/customView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- Your other elements are here -->

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**Your Java class of FragmentOne.java looks like:**

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
private MapView mapView;
private UiSettings mUiSettings;
private View customView
```

***onCreateView***

```
mapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

if (mapView != null) {
   mMap = mapView.getMap();
   mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
   mUiSettings = mMap.getUiSettings();
   mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
   mUiSettings.setCompassEnabled(true); 
   mUiSettings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
}


scrollViewParent = (ScrollView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.scrollViewParent);
customView = (View)rootView.findViewById(R.id.customView);

customView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int action = event.getAction();
                switch (action) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                        scrollViewParent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        // Disable touch on transparent view
                        return false;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        // Allow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                        scrollViewParent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                        return true;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        scrollViewParent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        return false;

                    default:
                        return true;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I had the added complexity of sitting inside a nested widget structure. But i finally found my way out by using your solution. (my scroll view was only reachable by using view.getParent())

Comment: works like charm,helped me when the top most voted answer failed in my case..thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I used this structures and I overcame the problem.

I used a container view for maps fragment.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:text="Another elements in scroll view1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        <com.erolsoftware.views.MyMapFragmentContainer
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp">

            <fragment
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/eventMap"
                tools:context="com.erolsoftware.eventapp.EventDetails"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

        </com.erolsoftware.views.MyMapFragmentContainer>

        <TextView
            android:text="Another elements in scroll view2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



    </LinearLayout>




</ScrollView>
```

The container class:

```
public class MyMapFragmentContainer extends LinearLayout {


    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
    {
        if (ev.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            ViewParent p = getParent();
            if (p != null)
                p.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public MyMapFragmentContainer(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyMapFragmentContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyMapFragmentContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to struggle with customScrollViews and transparent layout files. simply use lighter version of google map and your issue will be resolved.

```
  map:liteMode="true"
```

add above property inside map fragment in your layout file. and issue will be fixed.

Comment: Quicker, lightweight and better answer I think

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of the question - you can derive a fragment class from SupportMapFragment, and use that in your layout instead. You can then override [Fragment#onCreateView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle)), and instantiate your custom MapView there.

If that does not work, you can always create your own fragment - then you just need to take care of calling all the lifecycle methods yourself (onCreate, onResume, etc). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13824917/214837) has some more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
    ::
    ::
    ::
      <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/map_add_business_one_rl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
         >
                        <fragment

                            android:id="@+id/map"
                            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginTop="-100dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="-100dp"

                            />

        </FrameLayout>

    ::
    ::
    ::
     </ScrollView>
```