# Android Maps V2 MapView inside custom fragment (NPE)

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

I do not want to use or extend `SupportMapFragment` or `MapFragment`. I have my own base class with a bunch of code in it.

The documentation clearly states that when someone uses `MapView` by itself, all corresponding lifecycle methods (`onCreate()` `onResume()` etc.) should be called.

Most of the lifecycle methods in a `Fragment` are similar to an `Activity` but when I switch back and forth between my `Fragment` I eventually get an obfuscated NPE in `onDestroy()` or in `onResume()` methods.

All the samples provided use an `Activity` with a `MapView` but not a custom `Fragment`.

Has someone done that already? Can you provide sample code of a `MapView` in your own `Fragment`class?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I succeeded in including a MapView (v2) in a custom Fragment itself embedded in a ViewPager. In my case, the MapView is included in the Fragment layout file. I have had to call lifecycle methods on MapView (`onCreate()` called `onCreateView()` from the Fragment), and to call manually `MapsInitializer.initialize(context)` to avoid a `NullPointerException` from class BitmapDescriptorFactory (to get the bitmap for markers). This last trick is strange, and I don't know why the Map system isn't properly initialized itself without this call, maybe it's just a bug in the current version ...

In my case I haven't had any `NullPointerException` in `onResume()` or `onDestroy()`.

Comment: Here are some details about MapsInitializer.initialize(context) from the official documentation: 
[BitmapDescriptorFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/BitmapDescriptorFactory.html)
[MapsInitializer](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapsInitializer.html#initialize(android.content.Context))

Comment: clear I do have a Map object already but for some reason the exception is still thrown. It ended up working when I added this static ugly call.

Comment: @PoPy I'm trying to do the same as yourself (i.e : including mapView in a viewPager), but how do you do to keep mapView state (markers, position, zoom, ...). My state is lost when I go from page 1 (with map) to page 3, and return to page 1 !

Comment: @Sebastien I haven't tried to save the state for the moment, so sorry but i can't help you on this

Comment: @Sebastien I believe MapView.onSaveInstaceState method is for the problem you are having.

Answer (score 35):

I struggled a bit with PoPy's answer but in the end I managed it and here is what I came up with. Probably this is helpful to others which will also come across this issue:

```
public class MyMapFragment extends Fragment {

    private MapView mMapView;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Bundle mBundle;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, container, false);

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            // TODO handle this situation
        }

        mMapView = (MapView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.map);
        mMapView.onCreate(mBundle);
        setUpMapIfNeeded(inflatedView);

        return inflatedView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mBundle = savedInstanceState;
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded(View inflatedView) {
        if (mMap == null) {
            mMap = ((MapView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mMapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mMapView.onDestroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

And here is the corresponding `res/layout/map_fragment.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can omit the `RelativeLayout` (and move the xmlns declartion up to your new root element, in this case the `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView`) if you have just one element in your layout like in this example.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it helped me. However, are you using this in a view pager ? Because I have a problem with this solution and a view pager. I don't know how to keep map state (see my comment on PoPy's answer for more details). Could you help me ?

Comment: @jens thanx for the code, it works for the first fragment of my pager but when I swipe to 2nd fragment, the MapView shows nothing - it's like there was nothing in that frame.
FYI, the fragment transactions are done in the parent fragment's `onCreateView` method.
Another issue I have found - I have implemented `setOnMapClickListener` for the GoogleMap object but it seems all the clicks are not handled properly. It gets some of the clicks, not all. Don't know what happens here.

Comment: Update -
It seems that we have to call with `getChildFragmentManager()` from the parent fragment instead of `getFragmentManager()` to avoid the issue that map comes in only one fragment. But while swipe in pager, I am getting some **NullPointerException**.

Comment: Thanks for your implementation. I've noticed one issue. When restoring this map fragment from backstack, map camera position is lost. In my current implementation I use OnCameraChangeListener to save camera position each time it changes in fragment instance variable. When restoring fragment from backstack, I check this instance variable and if it is not null, move map camera to this saved position.

Comment: Then how to add/use this MyMapFragment  in my Activity? Can you please provide the complete example? I want to add mapview dynamically and moreover want to set width and height of mapview based on screen width and height. Please guide me for this..

Comment: @YuDroid You should create a new question here on SO for that. Because that's out of scope of the OP.

Comment: @pvshnik What callback do you use for restoring fragment from backstack, please?

Comment: I had to call `MapView.onDestroy()` and clear the `MapView` reference inside `Fragment.onDestroyView()` or else the resumed fragment was showing an empty gray map (kinda make sense since calling `MapView.onCreate()` inside `Fragment.onCreateView()`).

Answer (score -2):

While using a separate `MapView` following two things are of vital importance

```
    //at Activity
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      MapsInitializer.initialize(this);
      mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    }
    //or at Fragment
     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                       Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());  
       mapView.onCreate(mBundle);
     }
    //along with the following
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       if (mapView != null)
        mapView.onResume();
      }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();
       if (mapView != null)
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
      super.onLowMemory();
      if (mapView != null)
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }
```

Comment: @martyonair: Where have I called its twice? I have said at Activity or Fragment where you are using it. Please read it nicely and then only downvote

Comment: @laaptu Where did you initialize `mapView`?

Comment: @anoniim You can initialize either on `Activity` or `Fragment`,wherever you are using it

Comment: @laaptu I mean what method? Can't see it in your code snippet.

Comment: @anoniim You can add like `findViewById(R.id.yourgivenid)` on `Activity` `onCreate()` after setting `setContentView` or on `Fragment` `onCreateView`