# Map inside scroll view is shaking

Tags: android, scrollview, supportmapfragment

I am using the SupportMapFragment to display a static map in a ScrollView.

When I am scrolling down/up the map shakes inside its bounds, it feels pretty laggy. My question is, how to remove these shakes when scrolling

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/planebg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/category_image_tab"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/activity_details" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <com.jpardogo.listbuddies.lib.views.ListBuddiesLayout
                    xmlns:listbuddies="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:id="@+id/listbuddies"
                    android:layout_width="400dip"
                    android:layout_height="400dip"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-230dip"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:rotation="90" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/booknow"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/book_now" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="45dip"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="45dip"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/twitter" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="45dip"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/mail" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="45dip"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/cross" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dip"
                android:background="@drawable/layout_bgg"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <!-- <TextView -->
                <!-- android:layout_width="match_parent" -->
                <!-- android:layout_height="wrap_content" -->
                <!-- android:layout_marginLeft="5dip" -->
                <!-- android:layout_marginTop="15dip" -->
                <!-- android:textColor="#ffffff" -->
                <!-- android:textSize="22sp" /> -->

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/packageTxt"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="22sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/textbg" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                        android:text="Price"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="22sp" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/adult_ratetxt"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Adult:"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/child_ratetxt"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Child:"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/saveupTo"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="(Save up to 40% of our regular rate)"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="(Kids 4 and under: Free)"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Tax not included"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_height="65dip"
                android:src="@drawable/trip_adv" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/textbg" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                        android:text="Description:"
                        android:textSize="24sp" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dip" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/description"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                        android:maxLines="25"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />
                </ScrollView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/textbg" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_margin="5dip"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                    android:text="Location"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/addrTxt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/map_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp" >

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/map"
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="300dip"
                   />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="300dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
                <!-- <View -->
                <!-- android:layout_width="match_parent" -->
                <!-- android:layout_height="300dp" -->
                <!-- android:background="@android:color/transparent" /> -->
            </FrameLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dip" >
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MapFragment in ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746351/mapfragment-in-scrollview)

Answer (score 2):

If found this answer helpful:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/17315956/3353347

Essentially by adding a negative top and bottom margin the shuddering still occurs, but without the black/grey bars appearing at the top and bottom so it's not as noticeable.